# Polymer 1.0 paper-item vertical alignmen issue in IE

Tags: polymer

Why does the content of the paper-item not vertical centered in IE like in Chrome in the example here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <base href="//polygit.org/components/">
    <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="paper-item/paper-item.html">
</head>

<body>
    <template is="dom-bind">
        <paper-item style='background-color:Red'>Why is this not centered vertically in IE?</paper-item>
    </template>
</body>

</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/busemomecu/1/edit?html,output

?

Cheers